# Reshape matrix using Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I work using Matlab and I have a matrix in `400x400x3x3` shape. I need to reshape it into `1200x1200`. How do I do that?

I know there's a command called `reshape` and I've tried using it, but I'm missing something that I'm not seeing it.

Comment: HOW do you want to reshape it? (400x3) x (400x3) has two options

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess that you want dimensions 1 and 3 to collapse into a new first dimension, and dimensions 2 and 4 to collapse into a new second dimension.

In that case, you need [`permute`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) before [`reshape`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) so that the dimensions to be collapsed appear together:

```
x = rand(400, 400, 3, 3); % random data
y = reshape(permute(x, [1 3 2 4]), size(x,1)*size(x,3), size(x,2)*size(x,4));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = randn(400,400,3,3);
xr = reshape(x,1200,1200);
```

For an official reference, [nomen omen](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html). This is the most straightforward answer, but actually there are different approaches depending on how you want to structure your data.